# MS Access VBA to enable / disable a text box

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have the below VBA code in access to enable/disable a text box.

When the code is executed the tonnes textbox remains disabled.

Am I missing an additional property?

```
Private Sub EnableTonnes()

  Dim sCode As String
  sCode ="xx"


  ' set default values for tonnes enabled and locked properties
  Tonnes.enabled = False
  Tonnes.Locked = True

 If sCode = "xx" Then
    ' enable tonnes field
    Tonnes.enabled = True
    Tonnes.Locked = False
  End If

End Sub
```

Comment: unlock before enabling?

Comment: Good suggestion but it didn't work.

Comment: Some things to try: 1) Try stepping through the code line by line to ensure it actually gets inside the If block. 2) Try referencing Tonnes with Me.Tonnes, e.g., "Me.Tonnes.Enabled = False".

Comment: THanks for the suggestion but that did not help either.

Comment: Additionally the tonnes textbox is still disabled after removing the code and setting the tonnes control properties to enabled: yes and Locked: no

Comment: Found the issue. The underlying source is a calculated column in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks ok.  TextBox properties are set in form design mode and can only be permanently changed in form design mode.  You do some sophisticated coding to open the form in design mode, change the properties and then save the form... or do it manually. You will always be able to use your code to control those properties at runtime.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub cmdGo_Click()

    Dim sCode As String
    sCode = "xx"

    ' set default values for tonnes enabled and locked properties
    txtTonnes.Enabled = False
    txtTonnes.Locked = True

    If sCode = "xx" Then
        ' enable tonnes field
        txtTonnes.Enabled = True
        txtTonnes.Locked = False
    End If

    MsgBox txtTonnes.Name & " Enabled status is " & txtTonnes.Enabled
    MsgBox txtTonnes.Name & " Locked status is " & txtTonnes.Locked

End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
    MsgBox txtTonnes.Name & " Enabled status is " & txtTonnes.Enabled
    MsgBox txtTonnes.Name & " Locked status is " & txtTonnes.Locked
End Sub
```